# JSP is not running in IE8

Tags: jsp, internet-explorer-8

My webapp works fine with most of the browsers even with latest IE, but it won't load any jsp script (Such as drawing charts, submitting forms, etc) in IE8. 
Is there any work-around to enable jsp in IE8?

General Information about the app:

Backend: JAVA

Frontend: Javascript

Web Server: Tomcat 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert this in your jsp page

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
</head>
```

Otherwise check if the elements you are using are compatible with IE8.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp

**EDIT:** 
The `<meta>` tag should be added above the links to the `css` files.

```
 <head>
       <title>Page Title</title>
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
       <...>
 </head>
```